# Order a object's list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of objects where the object has 2 attributes: `id` and `name`.  I have to order the list by the name of the objects

How can I do this?

Comment: A bit more information on the object would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq is overkill for this when there are built-in methods to do this.

If you mean an array, just use `Array.Sort`:

```
Array.Sort(items, (x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

If you mean a `List<T>`, use the `Sort` function there:

```
items.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

Comment: +1 for using the native List support for sorting, rather than breaking out into Linq (not that there is anything wrong with Linq, but in this case it is overkill IMHO, and doesn't give any greater clarity of purpose either)

Comment: True about the using built in support, but as someone else said it doesn't take care of the null cases... Now you can change the above to take care of those cases but then the code isn't so clean any more. then its a choice between a simple orderby and the above with null checking... I'm on the fence as to which is better in that case...

Comment: @anthonyv - all fair points. And yes - it does lose some of its brevity once you put the null check in. Still - it is nice to see people put several different solutions on the table.

Comment: @Rob Agree completely with you on the having more than one answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using linq?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{ 
    public class Test
    {
        public void SortTest()
        {
            var myList = new List<Item> { new Item { Name = "Test", Id = 1 }, new Item { Name = "Other", Id = 1 } };
            var result = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a List of these objects, the easiest way is to supply a Comparison to the Sort method:

```
var list = new List<MyObject>();
...
list.Sort((item1, item2) => item1.Name.CompareTo(item2.Name));
```

(Above sample doesn't do null checking on the name)

This is nice and simple because string implements `IComparable<string>`. An alternative would be for you to implement `IComparable<MyObject>` on your class, and then you could just call `list.Sort()`

Answer (score 0):

The `Sort` method of the `List<T>` class has an overload that takes a custom comparison:

```
list.Sort((x,y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```